# How do I read content from a .txt file and then find the average of said content in Java?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, average, throws

I was tasked with reading a data.txt file using the scanner import. The data.txt file looks like this:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Q

I need to read and find the average of these numbers, but stop when I get to something that is not an integer.

This is the code that I have so far.

```
public static double fileAverage(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String i = input.nextLine();
    while (i.hasNext);
    return fileAverage(i); // dummy return value. You must return the average here.
} // end of method fileAverage
```

As you can see I did not get very far and I cannot figure this out. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First, your `Scanner` should be over the file `filename` (not `System.in`). Second, you should be using `Scanner.hasNextInt()` and `Scanner.nextInt()` (not `Scanner.hasNext()` and `Scanner.nextLine()`). Finally, you should add each `int` you read to a running `total` and keep track of the `count` of numbers read. And, I would use a `try-with-resources` statement to ensure the `Scanner` is closed. Something like,

```
public static double fileAverage(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename))) {
        int total = 0, count = 0;
        while (input.hasNextInt()) {
            total += input.nextInt();
            count++;
        }
        if (count < 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        return total / (double) count;
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I call this method then? im not able to call fileAverage(filename); anywhere after that because it says the code is unreachable or it says the return type is missing?

Comment: `fileAverage(filename);` - works fine here. How are you calling it? Which error is it? What version of Java are you targeting?

Comment: I am using javaSE-12 and am placing it after defining the method. i am getting errors that say code cannot be reached, return type is missing for the method, and something that says syntax error insert variabledeclaratorID.

Comment: Because you can't call a method without being in a block (usually in `main`).

Comment: Right. Okay i found my issue and got it all to work. Greatly appreciate your help!